# mAP decreases on re-training tensorflow object detection

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I tried to train the tensorflow object detection API on the pascalVOC dataset (for all 20 classes) using the faster_rcnn_resnet101 (trained on coco dataset with 91 classes) model as base model (provided in the repo). I used the config provided in the repo.

The training generated several .ckpt files at several iteration points including the ckpt files at iteration 0 (on which the training has no effect).

Then I performed the evaluation on the .ckpt files using the pascalVOC validation data for all 20 classes.

Important note: the 20 pascalVOC categories are actually a subset of the 91 Coco categories.

My evaluation results show that the performance for the 20 classes goes down by 15% and more for all iterations in the training. As per the config I ran the training for 200K iterations and kept all hyper-parameters the same as in the original graph.

My question is: Can anyone explain what is wrong here? Why does the performance (mAP) go down even though the pascalVOC categories are a subset of the Coco categories.
Also how can I ensure that the performance for these 20 classes do not go down even after subsequent training on datasets belonging to this class.

Or else please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Facing the same issue